Calculating Volume of Spherical Cap using triple integral in cylindrical coordinates and spherical coordinates
Given a sphere above of $xy$-plane with center $(0,0,0)$ and radius $2$ (the equation $z=\sqrt{4-x^2-y^2}$). Plane $z=\sqrt{2}$ intersect the sphere.

I want calculate volume of spherical cap (orange color) using triple integral. In cylindrical coordinates, I calculate as
$$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\int\limits_{\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt{4-r^2}}rdzdrd\theta$$
and the result is $\left(\dfrac{16}{3}-\dfrac{10}{3}\sqrt{2}\right)\pi$.
In spherical coordinates, I calculate as
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{\sqrt{2}}\rho^2\sin(\phi)d\rho d\theta d\phi$$
and the result is $\dfrac{4}{3}\sqrt{2}\pi$.
The result triple integral using cylindrical coordinates and spherical coordinates is different.
I'm sure using cylindrical coordinates the result is true.
In using spherical coordinates, I'm not sure the bound of integration is correct. I confused to determining the bound $\rho$ and $\phi$. What the correct bound of $\rho$ and $\phi$?

The proper integration limits in spherical coordinates are
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi/4} \int_{\sqrt{2}/\cos \phi}^2 \rho^2\sin \phi \, d\rho\, d\phi\, d\theta.
$$
This will lead to the same value as in cylindrical coordinates. To get the correct bounds, you need to think that:

$\phi$ is the latitude, measured starting at the north pole. If you start at the north pole ($\phi=0$) and descend to the equator on a meridian, the integration region ends when $z=\sqrt{2}$, which corresponds to $\phi = \frac{\pi}{4}$.
If you imagine straight lines starting at $(0,0,0)$ and passing through the integration region, you'll see that they first intersect the region when $z= \sqrt{2}$, which is equivalente to $\rho = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\cos \phi}$, and they exit the region at the sphere surface, where $\rho =2$.

